# How to convert a 2D array of integers to a 2D array of booleans using streams in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, java-stream

I have a 2D array of integers (0 or 1) like so...

```
int [][] gridInt = {
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
```

and I want to convert it to a 2D array of booleans using Java streams and .map(). The resulting array being:

```
boolean[][] gridBool = {
        {false, false, false, true, false, false},
        {false, false, true, true, false, false},
        {true, false, true, false, false, true},
        {false, false, false, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false, false, false}
    };
```

My latest attempt was:

```
boolean[][] gridBool = Arrays.stream(gridInt)
    .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
        .mapToObj(i -> i == 1)
        .toArray(Boolean[]::new)
    )
    .toArray(Boolean[][]::new);
```

But my code isn't compiling, the error message is:

```
error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        .toArray(Boolean[][]::new);
                ^
inferred: Boolean[]
upper bound(s): boolean[],Object
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `boolean` is not `Boolean`!

Comment: It's easy - Just change one lower case `b` to upper case `B`. `Boolean [][] gridBool`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you require a `Boolean[][]` as a result then it's as simple as changing the receiver type from `boolean` to `Boolean`:

```
Boolean[][] gridBool = Arrays.stream(gridInt)
                .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                        .mapToObj(i -> i == 1)
                        .toArray(Boolean[]::new)
                )
                .toArray(Boolean[][]::new);
```

However, it seems you want a `boolean[][]` as a result; unfortunately, since there is no `BooleanStream` it wouldn't be wise to perform this via a stream as readability or conciseness is not the best, rather an imperative approach would be better:

```
boolean[][] result = new boolean[gridInt.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < gridInt.length; i++) {
     boolean[] temp = new boolean[gridInt[i].length];
     for (int j = 0; j < gridInt[i].length; j++) 
          temp[j] = gridInt[i][j] == 1;         
     result[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did think of the iterative approach but I thought I could somehow use the map approach to make it easier/shorter. So I guess streams don't play well with primitive types other than int, long, and double? Or at least returning them?

Comment: @EJC yeah there have been a good number of questions in regard to why there is no `CharStream` or `BooleanStream`. when you want to convert a particular sequence of some type to a sequence of `char` or `boolean` it's not the most readable/concise and wouldn't be any better than using an imperative loop as there's no `CharStream` nor `BooleanStream`, however as you mentioned the other primitive types have specialized streams for each so they would be convenient.

Comment: @EJC if you wanted to use a stream for this, you would need to declare a `boolean[][] result = new boolean[gridInt.length][];` beforehand and then use `IntStream.range` + `forEach` to get the job done which is essentially what the above imperative approach does but in a more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the resulting `Array` to `Boolean`:

```
Boolean[][] grid1bool = Arrays.stream(gridInt)
                .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                    .mapToObj(i -> i == 1)  //Stream<Boolean>
                    .toArray(Boolean[]::new)
                )
                .toArray(Boolean[][]::new);
```

`mapToObj` requires an `Object`, not the primitive type `boolean`, so we cannot use `toArray(boolean[][]::new)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just simplify the logic as:

```
boolean[][] gridBool = new boolean[gridInt.length][gridInt[0].length]; // NxN grid
for (int i = 0; i < gridInt.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridInt[0].length; j++) {
        gridBool[i][j] = gridInt[i][j] != 0;
    }
}
```

***Note***: This avoids a temporary array creation for every iteration, hence would save you space further and also initialises the array with precise bounds upfront.